# Torr file on Mac El Capitan unable to find

Tags: mac

I have read through every forum I can find so far and have had no luck.

I installed Tor on a Mac with El Capitan. I have looked through the application itself and through the admin browser files and conducted a full system search for the torch file. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Torc using both direct download and terminal.

I can't find the torrc file anywhere.

Question) can I manually create a torrc file and point the torc to the location manually?

I am looking at hosting a website using Mamp pro with apache utilizing the mac as the server. So far I have the Mamp figured out but can't find the torc file in order to initiate complete hidden-services. The server will be hosted outside of the united states and I need to ensure the website traffic both in and out is hidden. If you have a good step by step for running a site from a mac with mamp with or without actually touching the torrc file I am all ears and ready to listen.

Thanks in advanced for the help.

Comment: To the manual creation, assuming you understand the bits in said file sure and use the flags as needed to point to it (manpage is your friend)